# Vue secrets in production

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nginx

How do I secure secrets in the Vue for production environments?  https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html is not secure as a solution.  In production I am using NGINX and Node.js serving inside an ECS Docker container.